# How to center an image and make it responsive and resizable as screen change?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm new to responsive design and CSS. It seems like a simple question but I can't get a straight answer from Google. I have tried http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ The ghost block works perfectly but it leaves me a white background colour. Now I'm stuck. Basically, I have a logo size 534x385 and I want this logo to be centered on any devices. In the case of mobile phones I would like this logo to shrink to match the screen size as well.

```
<div>
    <img class="logo" src="images/shapes-logo.png" />
</div>

.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top:15%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -267px;
} 

html {
    background: url('../images/shapes-background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here's my CSS so far. But if I do this the margin-left: -267px will cause problems in mobile devices.

Answer (score 5):

### Resizing the Object

To change the CSS property when the screen resizes, you can use

```
element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

You can specify your own values too to make them work. This way, everytime the screen shrinks the object or element gets smaller.

Other way, to get the mobile and tablets to get to work is the usage of CSS3 (Media Query)

Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  /* here comes the trick..this is the css, which would be applied to all 
   * the devices whose screen has a max-width of 400px..
   */
}
```

You can then set some properties for it, lets say you can change the image width to

```
img#logo {
   width: 50px;
}
```

So that, for smaller size screens the image width is just 50px.

Note that, this is also applied if the browser on desktop gets a width of 400px! This way, if the browser gets resized down to 400px width, the image will shrink to fit the place. In other words. Media Query is the best option to change the CSS properties depending on screen sizes. And again, you can use `width: 100%`.

To make the percentage thing work, you should use a container, such as `div` This way, the img will inherit the width of div and fill it. For example, if the div that wraps the image has 400px width, the image with `width: 100%` will have a width of 400% and so on.

### Centering the Object

The best method to center the object is to use margins. But not custom ones, but the browse generated.

Lets say, you want to align some image in the center of the page horizontaly, you can achieve that using `max-width: 100px` and `margin: 0 auto`. Like this:

```
img#id {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto; no vertical margin, auto horizontal margin
}
```

This way, the object will be placed in the center and the browser will automatically generate the margins for it. The max-width is to make sure, that it takes just the space it needs to. I created a site a fews days ago, you can check the image at the end of the page here: http://www.aceinternationals.com

You will see the image was never provided any code that has to be kept in mind, it is just max-width and margin. So when ever you use the browser resize function, the image will always come to the center.

### White background

White background might be because of the image's bckground color, or the background-color of the body! That might be inherited by the user agent (browser). I am not sure, why that happened! Sorry :)

#### Reference:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Good luck :)

Comment: You also need to add "display: block;" along with the width/margin attributes to center the object.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to add addition class with logo in html. 
like:--

```
<p class="classname"><div class="logo"><img /></div></p>

.classname{ text-align:center; width:100%; }
```

This will always keep your logo in center.

if it won't solve. use these with above css.

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

And also add:

```
.logo{ max-width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo {
width:33%;
background: url('your_logo.png');
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

your container:

```
html {
margin:auto;
}
```

You can try doing something like this. If you post a link I can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use max-width:100% for your image.  It will keep the image responsive.